# Ошибка при запуске фрагмента "Unable to start activity ... Error inflating class fragment"

Tags: android-fragment, android, activity

Из активити пытаюсь запустить фрагмент. Появляется такая ошибка:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class fragment.

Что она означает?

Comment: Что означает "запустить" фрагмент?

Comment: Убедись, что активити наследуется от FragmentActivity и что находиться на 31 строке в лейауте?

Comment: проверьте, не течет ли у Вашего приложения память.

Comment: Она значит, что у вас не все в порядке с ресурсами в приложении.    
Что бы вам сказали, как исправить, приложите код, как вы "запускаете" фрагмент, и xml файл layout фрагмента